# Jquery Mobile Slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can anybody help to get the image slideshow? Now the images just totally pasted on the webpage. Got totally lost! Tks! I will paste her html, js and css (3parts). I could not post this post owing to less details. I write here just some extra test, hopes that it is understandable.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
        <title>Panda</title>

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="gallerytest.css"/>


        <link rel="stylesheet" href="gallerytest.css"/>
        <script src="jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js"></script>

        <script src="jquery-ui-1.10.4"></script>
        <script src="slide.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body onload="Slider();"> 
        <div data-role="page" id="Home" data-theme="a">
            <div data-role="header" >
                <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul id="header">
                        <li><a href="home.html"><img src="images/home-black.png"/>&nbsp Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="donate.html">Donate</a></li>
                        <li><a href="about.html"><img src="images/info-black.png"/>&nbsp About</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>  
        <div role="main" class="ui-content">
                <h1 style="text-align:center">Gallery</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content" >  
        <div class="slider">
                <img id="1" src="images/full/001.jpg" border ="0" alt="Image001" />
                <img id="2" src="images/full/002.jpg" border ="0" alt="Image002" />
                <img id="3" src="images/full/003.jpg" border ="0" alt="Image003" />
                <img id="4" src="images/full/004.jpg" border ="0" alt="Image004" />
                <img id="5" src="images/full/005.jpg" border ="0" alt="Image005" /> 
                <img id="6" src="images/full/006.jpg" border ="0" alt="Image006" />
                <img id="7" src="images/full/007.jpg" border ="0" alt="Image007" />
                <img id="8" src="images/full/008.jpg" border ="0" alt="Image008" />
                <img id="9" src="images/full/009.jpg" border ="0" alt="Image009" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer">
            <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul id="footer">
                    <li><a href="card.html">Send me a Card!</a></li>
                    <li><a href="donate.html">Donate</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact me</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.slider{
    width:600px;
    height:600px;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:0;
    background-image:url('images/ajax-loader.gif');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    background:red;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).on("pageinit", function() {
    $(".slider #1").show("fade", 500);
    $(".slider #1").delay(5500).hide("slide", {direction:"left"},500);
    var sc=$(".slider img").size();
    var count=2;
    setInterval(function(){
        $(".slider#+count).show("slide",{direction:'right'},500};
        $(".slider#+count).delay(5500).hide("slide"{direction:"left"},500);
        if (count==sc) {
            count=1
        } else {
        count=count+1
        }
    }, 6500);
});
```

Comment: This is a mess.  I whipped up a Fiddle that is different in a few ways.  It's not on mobile (easily applied to mobile, though), and I'm using fades instead of slides (don't feel like learning how to do jQuery slides).

If I'm working in the wrong direction, let me know.  Look at this fiddle, see if it helps: http://jsfiddle.net/WJ3Hu/10/

Comment: sorry just took the background color red away. I did a test and check if css took any effects at all.

Comment: I didn't have your images to use, so I just used my own for demo purposes.  All you have to do is change the URLs of the images to your own and add as many as you want.  I deliberately left the code very open so you can change it as necessary.  The fiddle is only meant to use as a demo, not as a copy-paste solution.

Comment: I'm not sure if/when my edits will take form on StackOverflow, but I've removed a lot of unnecessary things and broken things from the code you provided.

Comment: -RobStemen. Tks for your effort. Btw, do you need to put this syntex in front of your js? $(document).on("pageinit",function(){     I just tried, still don't work. I realized those pictures also. sorry.

Comment: @RobStemen the errors you corrected were likely part of the problem and would have been better placed as an answer. If your edits suddenly make this work it can't be answered.

Comment: After taking a good, long look at the code, I finally figured out a workable solution for you.  Take a look at this fiddle and see if you can get it. http://jsfiddle.net/WJ3Hu/18/

Comment: @sanchothefat While they definitely brought it much, much closer to a solution, it still required some light tweaking to fix.  I think I solved it in my latest fiddle.  In either case, that was my bad.  Sorry for doing that.

Comment: @RobStemen it's better to provide an answer rather than fix it in the question though. Highlight the syntax errors that you fixed and why they were wrong so that the OP can learn from it. Link to your Fiddle from the answer then the OP can accept your answer and you get more rep.

Comment: @sanchothefat You're completely right.  Thanks for rolling it back for me.  I'll do that now.

Comment: For the last one, I tested. The ajax loader was loading all the time:-). NO picture even I replaced with mine

Comment: @Longway_togo Take `background-image:url('images/ajax-loader.gif');` this line out of your CSS and tell me if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so there are a few things wrong with this, but I think I got them all, so let's take a look.

First things first. The onload in your body (`<body onload="Slider();">`) and the pageinit function (`$(document).on("pageinit", function Slider() {...});`) are attempting to do the same thing.  The body onload, however, is not correct for what you're trying to do, so get rid of it (`<body>`).

Next, your div class that your jQuery is looking at is "slider();", but should just be "slider".  For starters, you're not trying to make a method call there.  Even if you were, that would be incorrect as the jQuery is going to handle that anyway.  Also, your jQuery is looking for `.slider`, not `.slider();` (is that even possible?), so change that to `<div class="slider">` and that'll fix it.

Next, the only reason you would provide a function name in a jQuery "on" method is if it were defined externally, and, in that case, you don't have to declare it, because you would have declared it outside of your function, so declaring `$(document).on("pageinit", function Slider() {...});` actually breaks it, so changing it to `$(document).on("pageinit", function() {...});` will take care of that.

That fixes all of the errors in your logic.  Next there are some syntactical errors that are giving you grief as well.  Namely, the following blocks of code.

```
$(".slider#1" + count).show("fade", 500);
$(".slider#1" + count).delay(5500).hide("slide", {direction:"left"},500);

$(".slider#+count).show("slide",{direction:'right'},500};
$(".slider#+count).delay(5500).hide("slide"{direction:"left"},500);
```

Let's look at the first block first.

The way you set this up, jQuery is looking for an item in your DOM with the class `slider` AND an ID of `1(count)` (for example, if `count = 2`, it would be searching for an ID of 12).  What you're trying to get it to do is show the first child of the slider element.  That means that the selector should be `$(".slider #1")`.  This will find the `.slider` element, then search it's immediate children for `#1`.

The second block shares the same issue, but with the added difficulties of not placing the quotes correctly.  What you need there is `$(".slider #" + count)`.  Finally, you need to use a parenthesis instead of a bracket (`$(".slider#+count).show("slide", {direction:'right'}, 500);`), and on the second line, you forgot a comma (`$(".slider#+count).show("slide", {direction:'right'}, 500};`).

Finally, since jQuery is toggling all of the images, you're going to want to hide all of the images at the beginning using the `display: none;` CSS property.

At this point, if the jQuery mobile stuff is configured correctly (unfortunately, Fiddle didn't let me use mobile stuff), you should now have a working slideshow!  Hopefully this helped you solve your problem and was also informative enough that you know how to do this in the future!  Good luck and happy coding!

Comment: Tks for your hard work. I will learn it point by point. Unfortunately I tried to run it through Chrome. the error code I got is Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND. It is related with jquery mobile -ui-1.0.4. I will try to figure out what's wrong with it. The problem is I didn't find the jquery ui 1.0.4 css downloaded version. I could only put that link. But anyway, you did a great job.Many tks!

Comment: No problem!  We've all been there, and it helps to have someone who can help when you get stuck.  If it helped you fix the problem, it was worth the time and effort.

Comment: Just to answer your last question, I took ajax loader away, pictures still does not show. It shows 9 icons. something wrong. There is no place here to send zip file. But I will try to solve it. Tks!

Comment: Forgot to mention this in my answer (will update it now), but in your CSS, you should add `display: none;` to your images.  Since they're being shown/hidden by jQuery, you want them all to start hidden

Comment: :-) I guess I will also vote for you in the future. Tks!